# Xamarin Forms default permissions

Tags: security, xamarin.forms

I have built a Xamarin.Forms app and scanned the apk using [MobSF](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF). In the generated report I realized that the following permissions were added even though those were not included in the AndroidManifest.xml;

- android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- android.permission.CAMERA

How can these permission be removed? I have already removed it from the AssemblyInfo.cs.

Also the iOS scan returns the following results;

- Binary make use of banned API(s) : The binary may contain the following banned API(s) _printf, _fopen, _strncpy, _memcpy, _strcpy, _stat, _chmod, _sscanf, _strlen.
- Binary make use of the insecure Random Function(s) : The binary may use the following insecure Random Function(s) _random.
- Binary make use of malloc Function : The binary may use malloc function instead of calloc.

I cannot see a clear justification for these. How can these be justified as those are presented by the Xamarin.Forms framework?

Comment: `_printf, _fopen, _strncpy, _memcpy, _strcpy, _stat, _chmod, _sscanf, _strlen.` these are the private APIs,references are typically used when using third-party libraries

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT is there any way to identify which third-party library is using it?

Comment: You can try to create a new project that does not reference any third-party libraries and locate it by elimination